# My first iPhone application testing

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Actually my iPhone is 2g model and iOS version is 3.1.3.

I have Mac OS X and Xcode 4.2.

I am a registered Apple iOS developer, I finished my test application. I am trying to deploy my application to iPhone.

When I connect my iPhone to my Mac, I go in Xcode, window - organizer then I get a message "iPhone requiries ios 3.0 - 3.2.2 Device Debugging support".

To use Lion User's iPhone for development, Xcode must download and install iOS 3.0 - 3.2.2 Device Debugging Support. you can see all available downloads in Xcode's Downloads preference panel.

I don't know where to download this package?

Comment: This is odd, however you may want to consider getting Xcode 4.3.3, and developing for iOS 4 and up targets. A VAST majority of iOS users are running iOS 4 and 5.

Answer (score 3):

You need to go to `XCode` `preferences` and then go to `Downloads` tab - `Components`

[image]

form here you can download device support.

Comment: ya you are correct but when i select the icon ios 3.0 - 3.2.2 Device Debugging Support and click install button means i got a message like The install path </volumes/xcode/xcode44-DP5.aa/contents/Developer> resides on a read-only volume. if you launched xcode from a read - only disk image, consider copying xcode to your Applications folder and unmounting the disk image.

Comment: are you using a Mac machine ?

Comment: ya am using vm ware mac machine

Comment: i am not 100 % sure but this may happening because you are using Developer Preview Version of XCode 5... what i suggest here you should use XCode 4.3.2 because XCode 5 is in DP.

Comment: am using  xcode 4.4 version.. now i should use xcode 4.3.2 am i right?

Comment: you are using xcode44-DP5 here DP means Developer Preview Version ... i am not sure but this issues is because of DP version , you can try XCode 4.3.2 which is working right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Deployment Target to 3.1.

Following is the path-

Project - Summary - Deployment Target

Comment: ya you are correct, i changed the target before starting the application development. But also same reaction.

Comment: then you need to download the device debugging support as mentioned  in above answer.

Comment: ya you are correct but when i select the icon ios 3.0 - 3.2.2 Device Debugging Support and click install button means i got a message like The install path </volumes/xcode/xcode44-DP5.aa/contents/Developer> resides on a read-only volume. if you launched xcode from a read - only disk image, consider copying xcode to your Applications folder and unmounting the disk image

Comment: i am not sure how to do this for VM.